# How to pass navigator.pop to custom react native component

Tags: navigation, react-native, components

I would like to extract my navigation menu into a custom component so I don't have to keep rewriting the code. Here is my simple dashboard.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
   StyleSheet,
   View,
   Text,
   Navigator,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

let HeaderMenu = require('../../partials/headerMenu');

class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HeaderMenu/>
   );
  }
}
module.exports = Dashboard;
```

Here is my headerMenu.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Navigator
} from 'react-native';

class HeaderMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View>
        <Text>Header Menu</Text>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.props.navigator.pop()}}>
         <Text>BACK</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = HeaderMenu;
```

My question is how can I pass:

```
   this.props.navigator.pop()
```

from my dashboard.js file to my headerMenu.js file so the back button works?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the Navigator object from dashboard.js into headerMenu.js:

```
<HeaderMenu navigator={your_navigator_object}/>
```

Then calling `this.props.navigator.pop()` in headerMenu.js should work.